# Cannot get click event in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('btn').click(function(){
                alert('hey'); 
            }); 
        });  
    </script>
</HEAD>
<button id="btn">click</button>
    Button to fire a event
</HTML>
```

I can't get a click event on IE8!
What i had done wrong?

Comment: You're missing the `#` from your selector: `$('#btn')`

Comment: Check you have a closing `</script>` tag and the `<body></body>`.

Answer (score 5):

Your selector is wrong

```
$('#btn').click( //<-- notice the pound sign
    function(){ 
        alert('hey'); 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`btn` is the ID of your element. So use **#** when you write the jQuery selector

```
$(function(){
  $("#btn").click(function(e){
         alert("hi");  
  });
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/RVJQU/

```
#  -> for ID based selector(Ex:   $("#myUniqueElementID") )
.  -> For CSS Class based selector (Ex:   $(".myCssClass") )
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
    <script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"/> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){  
            $('#btn').on('click',function(){
                alert('hey'); 
            }); 
        });  
    </script>
</HEAD>
<button id="btn">click</button>
    Button to fire a event
</HTML>
```